# How to get val from input type field for export pdf dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to get $("#kpm").val() for my title export pdf datatable
but when  i'm trying like this

js

```
table2 = $('#table2').DataTable({ 

    "processing": true, 
    "serverSide": true, 
    "order": [], 
    "ajax": {
        "url": site_url+"Laporan/runlaporan/transaksi_penjualan",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": function ( data ) {
            data.tgl = $('#tgl').val();
            data.tgl2 = $('#tgl2').val();
            data.nota = $('#nota').val();
            data.kpm = $('#id').val();
        }
    },

     dom: 'lBrtip',

     buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
             title: 'Laporan Transaksi Penjualan '+ $('#kodekpm').val(),
            orientation: 'landscape',

        }
    ]
});
```

html

```
<input type="text" name="kpm" id="kpm" placeholder="kpm" class="form-control">
```

result 
[image]
How to make title on export pdf datatable get value id=kpm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to call the generic `action()` programmatically with the modified `config` :

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
   dom: 'Bfrtip',
   buttons: [{
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
        config.title = 'Laporan Transaksi Penjualan '+ $('#kpm').val();
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.action(e, dt, button, config);
      }
    }]   
})
```

This will set both the `filename` and the `title` / header of the PDF.

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/Lsrx8ksx/**

**Tip**: If you define `config.filename`, like `config.filename = 'export';` then the downloaded file will be named `export.pdf` but the title inside the PDF will remain `Laporan Transaksi Penjualan +something`.

Comment: thanks, it's work can't you explaint what it's action() programmatically ?

Comment: @faza, because for some reason the modified `config` is not properly passed to the original `action()`, the custom `action()` method is called *after* and dataTables does not respond to changes to `config`, the export is already in progress. See this -> **https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33209/run-script-before-exporting-begins-buttons-plugin**